# long double vs double

Tags: c++, floating-point, long-double

I know that size of various data types can change depending on which system I am on.

I use XP 32bits, and using the `sizeof()` operator in C++, it seems like `long double` is 12 bytes, and `double` is 8.

However, most major sources states that `long double` is 8 bytes, and the range is therefore the same as a `double`.

How come I have 12 bytes? If `long double` is indeed 12 bytes, doesn't this extends the range of value also? Or the long signature is only used (the compiler figures) when the value exceed the range of a double, and thus, extends beyond 8 bytes?

Comment: This is the worst feature in ISO C. I strongly discourage you from using it. It only leads to problems because the specification is so loose.

Comment: @JeffHammond it can't be strict, otherwise how can C be available for 12, 16, 24, 36, 60, 72-bit systems? There's no way you can specify a fixed IEEE-754 floating-point format to run efficiently on a system with 72-bit non-IEEE float

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double):

> On the x86 architecture, most compilers implement long double as the 80-bit extended precision type supported by that hardware (sometimes stored as 12 or 16 bytes to maintain data structure .

and

> Compilers may also use long double for a 128-bit quadruple precision format, which is currently implemented in software.

In other words, yes, a `long double` *may* be able to store a larger range of values than a `double`.  But it's completely up to the compiler.

Comment: Data types depends heavily on the architecture you're developing for.

Comment: It also depends on compiler options. The 80-bit type can be explicitly disabled on almost every x86 compiler.

Comment: @karlphillip, @greyfade: Yes, I just meant "up to the compiler" in the sense that it decides how to store your data.  Obviously it's limited to what is available on the platform, and of course the compiler can choose to allow a user override.

Comment: Apple claims that `long double` is 128-bit: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/transition/transition.html

Comment: @AaronFranke that's the **size after padding**. The real underlying type is still 80-bit extended but padded to 12 bytes on x86 and 16 bytes on x86-64 for alignment reason. Almost all x86 compilers apart from MSVC do that. No one uses IEEE-754 quadruple precision for long double as that's extremely slow

Comment: @AaronFranke that's also specified by the [x86-64 SysV ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812/995714) which Unix (Apple included) uses. Just check `LDBL_MANT_DIG` and see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19237884

Answer (score 20):

For modern compilers on x64, Clang and GCC uses 16-byte double for `long double` while VC++ uses 8-byte double. In other words, with Clang and GCC you get higher precision double but for VC++ `long double` is same as `double`. The modern x86 CPUs do support these 16-byte doubles so I think Clang and GCC are doing the right thing and allows you to access lower level hardware capability using higher level language primitives.

Comment: The size is 16 bytes but 6 bytes of that is padding. `long double` is always 80-bit extended by default, padded to 12/16 bytes on x86 and x86-64 respectively. You can change the size via [`-mlong-double-64/80/128` options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) if you're willing to break the ABI or some APIs. There are also `-m96/128bit-long-double` to change the padding size

Answer (score 5):

The standard byte sizes for numbers are the guaranteed minimum sizes across all platforms. They may be larger on some systems, but they will never be smaller.