# Two data types used in function definition to_string(long double _Val)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to understand expression below:

```
inline string to_string(long double _Val)

{   // convert long double to string
char _Buf[_MAX_EXP_DIG + _MAX_SIG_DIG + 64];

_CSTD sprintf_s(_Buf, sizeof (_Buf), "%Lg", _Val);
return (string(_Buf));
}
```

Why two data types is used in parameter definition? Is this decried in c++ standard?

Comment: that's 1 type - called `long double`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double

Answer (score 0):

That is the actual type. It is called `long double`. You can read up on it at wikipeida: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double

You can read more here: [long double vs double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454576/long-double-vs-double)

Answer (score 0):

It's a single data type:

`long double` - extended precision floating point type. Does not necessarily map to types mandated by IEEE-754. Usually 80-bit x87 floating point type on x86 and x86-64 architectures.

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types