# How to pass Mat_<long double> in function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `Mat_<long double>` matrix. I need `long double` to perform multiplication of large matrices (10x4096 both). But the problem is that passing to function in such way: `func(Mat first)` makes the size of element in function 8 bytes though I need 16. But `func(Mat_<long double> first)` causes undefined reference to function by linker. So the question is how can I pass `Mat_<long double>` to function?

Comment: are you sure that `long double` is 16 bytes?

Comment: I beg to differ @tobi303 . It is far less comprehensible after even a single pass of ROT13. Strangely a second pass seems to recover... I wonder how that happened.

Comment: @Tehada: check sizeof(long double) to know how many bits it is on your implementation. It's not a standard size.

Comment: @JasonLang I already solved! The problem that I forgot to fix prototype of function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the prototype of the function to pass diferent parameter type:

Prototype:

```
func(Mat_<long double> first);
```

Definition:

```
func(Mat_<long double> first)
{
..
}
```

Usage:

```
Mat_<long double> example;
func(example);
```

**Notes:**

- Be careful with the use of `long double`, isn't very portable, as [different compilers treat it differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454576/long-double-vs-double)
- Also consider to pass by reference (`Mat_<long double> &`) instead of by val for performance reasons, when you use a big matrix.

Comment: Yes, the problem in declaration, I didn't change it!

Comment: long double isn't very portable however, as different compilers treat it differently.

Comment: @JasonLang, Thanks, I added your comment as a note in the body