# Substitutions for Eigen::MatrixXd typedefs

Tags: c++, typedef, eigen, long-double

What is the simplest way to replace all `Eigen::MatrixXd`s and `Eigen::VectorXd`s with Vectors and Matrices that have `long double` elements?

Every basic floating point variable in my code is of type `long double`. Also, everytime I use a matrix or vector, I use the following typedefs.

```
typedef Eigen::VectorXd Vec;
typedef Eigen::MatrixXd Mat;
```

What's the best thing to switch these typedefs to? What happens if I leave them as they are?

Comment: The more important question is however, do you really need `long double`?  It might significantly slow down all your calculations because most processors are built to do `double` arithmetic fast.  Also it might be that your compiler just ignores `long double` and uses `double` instead.  Read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) and think about it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply define your own typedefs based on Eigen's own [global matrix typedefs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html).

If you use `Eigen::MatrixXd` and fill it with elements of type `long double`, those values will be narrowed to fit into the `double` elements of the matrix, which results in a loss of precision or, in the worst case, overflow errors.  However, on many architectures double-precision floating point arithmetic is done in 80-bit extended precision, so the results may be the same.  You surely shouldn't rely on this!  For more see, e.g., [long double vs double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454576).

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

typedef Eigen::Matrix< long double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1              > Vec;
typedef Eigen::Matrix< long double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic > Mat;

int main()
{
  long double ld = 2;

  Mat m(1,1);
  m(0,0) = ld;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I saw that link and was wondering about the difference between `long double` as the first template parameter and `std::complex<long double>.' And I'll look into that other thing thanks