# Stack overflow in area calculation

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, polygon, area

I have N points in trigonometric order that define a polygon. I've used the following code to calculate the area of that polygon but I get a stack overflow and I can't exactly understand why. At first I thought it was the while function getting out of bounds but apparently is not?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

struct punct {
    long double x;
    long double y;
};

int main()
{
    int N;
    long double aria = 0.0f;
    punct v[100000];
    ifstream f("aria.in");
    ofstream g("aria.out");
    f >> N;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        f >> v[i].x >> v[i].y;
    }

    int k = 1;
    while (k <= N - 1) {
        aria = aria + (v[k].x * v[k + 1].y - v[k + 1].x * v[k].y);
        k++;
    }

    aria = aria + (v[N].x * v[1].y - v[1].x * v[N].y);
    aria = 1 / 2 * aria;

    g << aria;

    f.close();
    g.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My input file `aria.in` has the following:

```
4
-2 -2
2 -2
2 2
-2 2
```

Comment: Which code is the last one still executed? What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: Do not allocate huge arrays such as `punct v[100000];` on the stack because stack space is rather limited. Allocate them on the heap using `::std::vector`.

Comment: It's likely the fault of `punct v[100000]`. You're allocating **lots** of stack space for this array `16 * 100000 =~ 1.5MB`. Try heap allocation instead. A clue: [use vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @tomix86 I think long double are (typically) 10 bytes each? Also... reply OP: It's possible to increase stack size by commands (differs for each OS)

Comment: @user202729 AFAIK it is architecture and compiler dependent, long double should be *at least* 8 bytes long, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454576/long-double-vs-double). I've done a quick check and with VS2017 compiled for x64 it is indeed 8 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
punct v[100000];
```

Is in error as it is too big for the stack

Use `std::vector` instead i.e.

```
#include <vector>

....

std::vector<punct> v(100000);
```

Also you should check if you have actually opened the files

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to malloc 100000 `punct` on the stack, which leads to a stack overflow.

You can malloc on the heap as:

```
punct *v = new  punct[100000 + 1];
```

This should resolve the stack overflow.
For completeness, it is good to free the memory after no needed.

```
delete [] v;
```

You can also use c++11 new `vector`

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<punct> v(100000 + 1);
```

or `array` container to do it

```
#include <array>
std::array<punct, 100000 + 1> v;
```

Noticed that I add-ed one to `100000`, due to that your code looks like 1-starting index based. However, c++ counts index from `zero`. It is your choice though.